# TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746 / No Connectivity via PHP and Apache2

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I've installed the ODBC Drivers for Microsoft SQL Server on Debian 11 and configured everything appropriately. When I call the PHP script via

> php /var/www/html/sqlsrv.php

everything is working as excepted. When calling the PHP via browser I am constantly getting the following error

> SQL Error: Error information: SQLSTATE: 08001 Code: 10054 Message:
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code
> 0x2746 SQLSTATE: 08001 Code: 10054 Message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18
> for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection

Here is my PHP so far:

```
  <?php

 
$serverName = "xxx\SESQL";
$connectionOptions = array(
    "database" => "SEMESS",
    "uid" => "xxx",
    "pwd" => "xxx",
    "TrustServerCertificate" => "yes"
);

 
// Establishes the connection
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);
if ($conn === false) {
    die(formatErrors(sqlsrv_errors()));
}

// Select Query
$tsql = "SELECT @@Version AS SQL_VERSION";
$tsql2 = "SELECT * FROM BENUTZER";

// Executes the query
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);
$stmt2 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql2);

// Error handling
if ($stmt === false) {
    die(formatErrors(sqlsrv_errors()));
}
?>

<h1> Success Results : </h1>

<?php
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['SQL_VERSION'] . PHP_EOL;
}

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt2, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
  var_dump($row);
}



sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
sqlsrv_close($conn);

function formatErrors($errors)
{
    // Display errors
    echo "<h1>SQL Error:</h1>";
    echo "Error information: <br/>";
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        echo "SQLSTATE: ". $error['SQLSTATE'] . "<br/>";
        echo "Code: ". $error['code'] . "<br/>";
        echo "Message: ". $error['message'] . "<br/>";
    }
}
?>
```

I've added

> "TrustServerCertificate" => "yes"

as without it a connection was not possible.

- Also, I've updated to OpenSSL 1.1.1 - do I need to update Apache as
  well? If, how?
- Why is it working with PHP CLI but not with PHP Apache?

Comment: Aside... if the [PHP documentation](https://php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.requirements.php) is to be believed, the SQLSRV extension only works on Windows Vista, 7 and Windows Server 2008/R2. Would be nice if they kept that up to date.

Comment: It should work the same in both places, but have you tried escaping the blackslash that delimits the server name from the instance name? i.e.: `$serverName = "xxx\\SESQL";`

Comment: How many php.ini files are on your system? i.e.: `sudo find / -name php.ini` It's not uncommon for `cli` to have a separate configuration from `apache`.

Comment: $serverName = "xxx\\SESQL"; is not working ... I'll try to edit all appropriate php files